# Calculate Relationship between coordinate systems

Tags: coordinate-systems, coordinate-transformation, rotational-matrices

I am trying to find the  relationship (xyz and rotation) between two coordinate systems (A and B) that are both offset (in xyz and rotation) from the world coordinate system. I have 4x4 matrices for A and B relative to the world coordinate system, but i need a matrice  for B relative to A.

Comment: Just multiply A^-1 * B, where matrix A transforms world system to A and matrix B transforms world sysrem to B.

Comment: Sorry, calculation i wrote is in wrong order I think. Should be B * A^-1.

Comment: Thankyou, just got to work that out into code now.

Comment: Thankyou, got it coded and working.

Comment: B * Inverse (A)